# How to create a statistics dashboard of my users using Views?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, dashboard

I'm working on a Drupal website based on its users. They can login, pay their debts, set and update their personal and contact information, etc.

I would like to create a Dashboard showing statistics of these users, based on my user's fields, something like:

- **GENDER:** Male 54% - 46% Female
- **ACTIVE USERS:** 67%
- **AGES:** 20% KIDS - 56% Young - 16% Old - 8% Other

I even have a design for it, I´m just trying to figure it out technically using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module and its integration with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. A straight forward cloning of the delivered views example would do what you are asking for. Have a look at [this online example](http://drupal.placeto.be/charts/examples/views) to get a first impression.

Some more examples of the Charts integration with Views, using data contained in "nodes" (so not using any Views aggregation facilities):

- [Single chart, not attached to a table, and without aggregation](http://drupal.placeto.be/single_chart_with_no_aggregation_not_attached_to_table).
- [Table with attached charts, and without aggregation](http://drupal.placeto.be/table_with_attached_charts_and_no_aggregation).
- [Combination chart without aggregation](http://drupal.placeto.be/combination_chart_with_no_aggregation).

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts).

Answer (score 4):

You can also do just normal (the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) blocks, maybe a **charts view** using any of the charting modules mentioned in the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985). And place the block(s) on the default drupal dashboard.

Comment: Please check my edited version of your answer (in which I tried to make the link title match the title of the linked page (+ merci for "the mention" ..). Feel free to further refine / edit of course. PS: why not include a recommendation of which of those charting module you'd go for?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wish to create an Admin dashboard with no coding:

You will need more than one view. You either have multiple views or a single view with attachments. If it is multiple views you will have to find a way of embedding them on one page, probably using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).

Your view(s) will use aggregation as you are accumulating stats by grouping.

**Modules that might assist:**

Page Manager (part of [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools))

[Contextual Administration](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_admin) which is a nice module to assist in creating admin path dashboards:

> Contextual Administration is an administration tool based on CTools
>   Page Manager module. It allows for the deployment of custom
>   administrative pages through a typical database driven mechanism or
>   can take advantage of the typical page_manager exports through custom
>   modules + exports or features module.

Tutorial for using Contextual Administration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Luc-bGGxa6c&list=PLEFD8FDE69D61DCA3